Как расположить текст в кнопке (button) на одном уровне (по baseline) с текстом тега <p>?

Здравствуйте, как установить текст в кнопке (button) на одном уровне (по baseline) с тегом "p". Почему-то inline-flex поднимает кнопку на пару пикселей. Какой стиль необходимо применить к кнопке, что бы она была на одном уровне как на картинке (синим обвёл).
Код пишу в tailwindCSS, если есть у кого возможность помочь, буду благодарен.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/kPWbFYdDbV
P.S.
Я не программист, работаю инженером в больнице, пытаюсь написать сам "систему учета средств измерений", поэтому даже базовых аспектов могу и не знать.

.cta-secondary поставьте heigth: 17px; так как те что слева стоят у вас равняются 17px, а .cta-secondary сейчас 13px. Поэтому он выше

Спасибо, Евгений, Вы помогли. Действительно, если добавить к кнопке heigth: 17px, то она сместится на необходимый уровень. А можно еще один дурацкий вопрос, Я за основу брал Footer сайта https://monogrid.com/ (там как раз эта кнопка), но в стилях Я так и не нашел решения которое Вы мне подсказали (добавить heigth:17px) , они этого добиваются с помощью JS или существуют еще какие-то варианты, как можно достичь сдвига текста?

не понял о чём вы, на сайте том не нашёл я такой кнопки, если вы про меню, то он там также все три пункта с одинаковой высотой, а у вас просто вместо третьего пунка кнопка

всё я понял о чём вы, там у них тоже не ровно стоит если что. Back to Top кнопка у них на один пиксель выше стоит. И также если присмотритесь у них кнопка 13 пикселей, а другие 16.9, считай 17

ок, понял, спасибо, доверюсь профессионалу))

Пишу же, так же как и у вас. у них он не ровно стоит по отношению к MENU, EXTERNAL и CONTACT. тоже он выше у них на пиксель. Если решили заняться вёрсткой - скачайте mySize, очень вам поможет.
